# Android device camera with video mode and photo mode

Tags: android

I want to bring up device camera so that the user can swap between camera and video mode. Is that possible to do? Please help me out with this asap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following Intent ->

```
        Intent i=new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_VIDEO_CAMERA);
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: It worked!! how can i identify whether its a video or photo after the camera is closed? So that i can take actions from the intent

Comment: Sorry, I didn't try it yet. Consider post as an another question.